# Sending newsletters with SendGrid and Rails - What is the best approach?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid, actionmailer, newsletter

I have a rails app with sendgrid API setup and I can send transactional emails just fine. Now I want to be able to send newsletters but I'm a bit confused about the flow and how to keep track of which users want to unsubscribe from the newsletter.

The way I was considering doing this is when a use signsup to automatically send a request to the SendGrid API and add them to the `contacts` list, and if they want to unsubscribe from the newsletter or transactional emails from my app's settings page I can save this info in my app's DB but also send a request to sendgrid's unsubscribe list to change the value there too. Now I can create a newsletter in sendgrid and send it out from there without having to do anything within my app. One caveat to this approach would be if the users clicks the unsubscribe button via the newsletter and the value gets changed in sendgrid but the change won't be reflected in my app - To work around this would it be better to create a cron job that periodically checks sendgrid for any changes and then save them to my DB, or should the unsubscribe page be part of my app, and when they select unsubscribe I save it to my DB and then push the changes to sendgrid? If i do this approach, would I require users to sign in if they want to make these changes?

An alternative approach would be to forego creating any contact lists in sendgrid and just create the email in sendgrid and sent it out using a rake tasks to trigger the sending?

Apologies if this is a very basic question, but this is my first time trying to setup newsletters etc and can't seem to find anything online about the best strategy to take in order to do this - I hope this question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

This question is a little too opinion based for Stack Overflow, many of the options you describe will work but they rely on whether it's the right decision for your application. But, I will try to give some guidance.

First, however you approach this, I would recommend you set up [subuser accounts within SendGrid](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/subusers) so that your transactional and newsletter emails come from different subusers. This way unsubscribes from newsletters won't affect transactional emails.

I would use the SendGrid contacts list to send out newsletters. This gives you a lot of power over your contacts without you having to build things yourself. You can segment your lists, create [unsubscribe groups](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/unsubscribe-groups) (where a user can unsubscribe from a subset of your emails instead of all of them) and send emails from within SendGrid without bothering your Rails app. You can still set up to [trigger a newsletter from your app using the API](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/single-sends/create-single-send) if you want to.

As for maintaining the user's subscription status, I would go with exporting the contact lists and keeping your database up to date that way. The important thing when sending to your contact list is that SendGrid has the source of truth for subscription status and your application can be a bit behind if it needs to be. [The SendGrid docs for exporting contacts also say](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/contacts/export-contacts):

> Twilio SendGrid recommends exporting your contacts regularly as a backup to avoid issues or lost data.

So this would fulfil that suggestion too.

As for the unsubscribe links, the easiest way is to use the SendGrid unsubscribe form, have SendGrid handle all the unsubscribes, and your exports can keep your database up to date. That also allows you to handle the addition of unsubscribe groups without any more code on your side.

With more work you could create your own unsubscribe form so that your database stays more up to date with the subscription status. Your choice over whether a user should be logged in or not depends on how much friction you want to give the user before they unsubscribe and how much issue you think you might get from users forwarding your emails and having their friends unsubscribe them. That is up to you to decide on though.

Hope this helps a bit!